# Using ignoreUnknownValues from Hadoop BigQuery Connector

Tags: hadoop, google-bigquery, google-hadoop

I'm piping unstructured event data through Hadoop and want to land it in BigQuery. I have a schema that includes most of the fields, but there are some fields I want to ignore or don't know about.

BigQuery has a configuration field called [ignoreUnknownValues](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs), but I can't figure out how to turn that on from the Hadoop connector. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the BigQuery connector for Hadoop doesn't support this at the moment; we'll be sure to add more flexible config customizations in the next release and direct support for the known configuration settings like `ignoreUnknownValues`. In the meantime, if you're up for building from source, you should be able to add after [line 317 of BigQueryRecordWriter.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/master/bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/hadoop/io/bigquery/BigQueryRecordWriter.java#L317):

```
loadConfig.setIgnoreUnknownValues(true);
```

Then you simply `mvn -Phadoop1 package` or `mvn -Phadoop2 package` and upload your custom BigQuery connector jarfile to some location in GCS, and finally modify `BIGQUERY_CONNECTOR_JAR` in your `bdutil_env.sh` to point to your custom jarfile before re-deploying.